# Issue checking if row exist?

Tags: php, mysql, class

How can I check if a MySQL row exists using PHP? And then return true or false?

I tried this:

```
// Does a game with that url-name exist?
public function nameExist() {
    return $this->db->execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `main_games` WHERE `url`=?', array($this->getSubdomain()));
}
```

Here is the source of the class:
http://pastebin.com/p17gUEPA

And here is the source of the hook where I run this class from:
http://pastebin.com/WjSNLCMd

Comment: how does what you have tried fail ?

Comment: If you count all rows just to check if one row exist that could be really slow, depending on how many rows match. Consider someone asking you "Is there anyone in the stadium?". You go into the stadium and see that it's packed full. An ordinary person would just walk out at that point and say "yes". But with your approach you'd have to first count exactly how many people there are in the stadium. Only once you have counted every single person can you then walk out and say "yes". Obviously that's much slower.

Comment: That will probably return a resultset, or maybe a scalar (the count), but it will not return true, ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at what execute returns:

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

So even if there are 0 rows but executing the statement succeded, then you will still get a true. What you can do is use [fetchColumn()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) to actually get the number of rows and return that. Something like this:

```
public function nameExist() {
    $stmt= $this->db->execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `main_games` WHERE `url`=?', array($this->getSubdomain()));
    return $stmt->fetchColumn() 
}
```